# usage of 懐かしい for self

Tags: grammar, i-adjectives

I have a question about 懐かしい. I see it translated as "nostalgic", but i seem to understand it would be closer to "(something) that makes you feel nostalgic".

My question is : can 懐かしい be used to describe my state of mind as in :

懐かしいです - i feel nostalgic ?

Or can it only be used to describe an object, period or event that **makes** you feel nostalgic ?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the subject of the 懐かしい adjective is the thing that's considered to be nostalgic. In other words, the sensory input (or memory/thought/etc) that ellicits the nostalgia.

However, if you want to emphasize the state of mind (i.e., the feeling) of nostalgia, you can do so by combining 懐かしい with 気持ち. For example:

> あの道を歩いたら、何となく**懐かしい気持ち**になってきた。

Answer (score 0):

Use "nostalgic" for self without showing anything concrete.

(私は) "なんだか" 懐かしい

"なんだか" is the same as "somehow".
In this case, I can't explain what caused the nostalgia.